# why are manhole covers round? does the square manhole cover really will fall if its put diagonally?

Tags: mathematical-physics, education

This is an interview question and its answers say that if the cover is a square then it will fall inside when put diagonally? But how will it fall if the filling area is a smaller square? Is the filling area not small then how is it made

Comment: Of course a square manhole cover will fall through the square opening if you hold the plate vertically and rotate it $45^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course a square manhole cover will fall through the square opening if you hold the plate vertically and rotate it $45^\circ$ about the vertical.  The problem has nothing whatsoever to do with area.
Does this help?

[image]

By the way, look up Reuleaux triangle!